# using JdcbTemplate standalone

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

We are looking into using the JdbcTemplate for accessing the DB - but we have many different DB-connections, that each class could use, so injecting the jdbcTemplate is not an option atm. So if we do a

```
jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
```

what will the transaction policy be? Auto-commit is off in the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure each `javax.sql.DataSource` object to enable auto-commit if that does the job, or disable auto-commit and write the transaction logic programatically.

Both the `java.sql.Connection` and the `javax.sql.DataSource` class have methods for enable/disable auto-commit.

Regarding dependency injection and Spring, you can still inject a datasource object into your repository. If you also let each repository extend the `org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport` class, then you have a JdbcTemplate object available for you with the derived `getJdbcTemplate()` method.

You can also let Spring handle the transaction handling for you. Without a XA transaction manager, you need one transaction manager for each datasource. With many transaction managers, declarative transaction support with the `@Transactional` annotation is impossible. You can however, inject the transaction manager into your service class. This is described in the reference documentation [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate-tx-programmatic).

Comment: So I guess, the JdbcTemplate will simply commit after every update, if nothing else is specified?

Comment: That is default behaviour for every `DataSource` I have used. So it should, but check your `DataSource` configuration if the `JdbcTemplate.update(..)` doesn't commit.

Comment: javax.sql.DataSource does not have any mention of auto commit.